# reset a UI switch when using AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UISWitch` default position set as`off`

Switch optionally is set to `on` by the user,  How can I turn that switch back to off from another button/action.

```
- (IBAction)switchToggled:(id)sender {

if (_toggle.on){


  AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ( [backCamera isTorchAvailable] && [backCamera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]  )
{
    BOOL success = [backCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if ( success )
    {
        [backCamera setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [backCamera unlockForConfiguration];
      }
    }
}

else {

    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ( [backCamera isTorchAvailable] && [backCamera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]  )
    {
        BOOL success = [backCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if ( success )
        {
            [backCamera setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [backCamera unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }

}
```

reset switch state from ui button:

```
  - (IBAction)toggledOffSwitch:(id)sender {
     _toggle.on = NO; 
    }
```

or

```
  - (IBAction)toggledOffSwitch:(id)sender {
  [_toggle setOn:NO];
  [_toggle setEnabled: NO];
   _torch.enabled = NO;
   _torch.on = NO;

  }
```

doesn't seem to be doing it

Updated with  more code

Comment: @Gobot has the best guess.  setOn, .on=, and setOn:animated: are synonyms, the latter will perform animation.  setEnabled: change enabled state, not on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this one out

```
 - (IBAction)toggledOffSwitch:(id)sender {


AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ( [backCamera isTorchAvailable] && [backCamera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]  )
{
    BOOL success = [backCamera lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if ( success )
    {
        [backCamera setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [backCamera unlockForConfiguration];

        _torch.on = NO;
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you hooked up your `- (IBAction)toggledOffSwitch:(id)sender` action up in Xcode?

Comment: Log out your `_toggle` switch in your methods, are you sure it is not `nil`?

Comment: The button action is working fine.  Its to do with the code for back light, when I comment that out, reseting the switch state works.

Comment: Is the `_toggle` button initiating those actions, or is some other UI element firing them?

Comment: Yep, `_toggle fires` the initial action, `_toggledOff`, is a UIBtn turning it off again

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method?

```
- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated
```